# Confused about python syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, notation

I have looked all over the web and have not been able to find an answer to my question. I am trying to understand some python code and came across a class declaration that looks like this:

```
s_list = []    
last_name = ""

def __init__(self, last_name, curr_date, difference):
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.s_list = {curr_date:difference}
    self.d_list = []
    self.d_list.append(curr_date)
```

What is happening inside the curly braces? Is this initializing a dictionary? Later in the main file it is used like this:

```
n = n_dict[last_name]
n.d_list.append(curr_date)
n.s_list[curr_date] = difference
```

Where n is a temporary dictionary used to add onto n_dict, with n_dict being a dictionary that contains information about the class.

Why is the {:} notation used? Is there any other way this could have been done?

Any answers much appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Yes, `{curr_date:difference}` initializes a dictionary. It could also be written as `dict(((curr_date, difference),))`.

Comment: To be fair, `s_list` is a very poor name for a dictionary. It is undersood by Python, but it makes it harder for the next dev to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{curr_date:difference}` created an anonymous dictionary.Instead, you can create a dictionary with a name :

```
dict_name={}
dict_name[curr_date]= difference
self.s_list=dict_name
```

Also, you can even create a dictionary using `dict()`:
    
`self.s_list=dict(curr_date=difference)`

There are some other ways to create a dictionary in python!

Comment: A "dictionary literal", not an "anonymous dictionary".

Comment: `dict_name`, not just `dict`. Also : "a dictionary with a name". It doesn't work this way : `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`. You just initialized a variable with a dict object. It doesn't mean that this dict object has a name

Comment: That's my fault, it's a slip of the pen. I have edited my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just compliment to the answer, which didn't explain the confusing code. 
Indeed, the code is written is pretty confusing. This involve globalise and localised variable concept.

```
# This is the global list variable
s_list = []    

# this is the global 
last_name = ""

def __init__(self, last_name, curr_date, difference):
    # Everything define here is localised and will be used first
    # pass value from given to last_name (not using above global last_name)
    self.last_name = last_name

    # This localised assignment make self.s_list a dictionary
    self.s_list = {curr_date:difference}
    # create another list
    self.d_list = []
    self.d_list.append(curr_date)
```

IMHO, the example is some sort of tutorial to point teach about global vs local variable, and together with bad naming examples.